# Относительный путь и слеш

Tags: php, yii, linux

В общем, есть два идентичных проекта на yii на двух разных машинах (на одной стоит lamp, а на другой - xampp, на обоих машинах стоит debian). На первой машине работает путь типа (и это правильно): `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile('/public/css/main.css');`, а на другой (там, где xampp стоит) правильным путем считается вот такой: `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile('public/css/main.css');`.
Вопрос: как это поправить? Что где дописать и почему такое произошло?

Comment: Добавить точку перед слешем. Произошло потому, что сервер посчитал путь как абсолютный.

`Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile('./public/css/main.css');`

Comment: А как сказать серверу, что ему надо такой путь считать относительным?

Comment: Точка, смотрите выше.

Comment: @makbeth

1. > Добавить точку перед слешем
2. прочитать про устройство файловой системы, в частности UNIX

Comment: @jackrv Наверное, я не так выразился. В том-то и дело, что в пути менять ничего нельзя. Ни точек добавлять, ни слеши убирать. Нужно где-то подправить какую-то настройку сервера, но где и какую, я тут и пытаюсь выяснить.

Answer (score 1):

Очень похоже, что разница в том, что в одном окружении проект в корне домена, а на другом в подпапке. Если это так, то добавьте `Yii::app()->baseUrl`:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile(Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/public/css/main.css');
```

С точками и относительными путями играться не стоит. Если включить `urlFormat = path` в конфиге для `urlManager`, то относительные пути сыграют с вами злую шутку. Например, путь к стилям `public/css/main.css` для урла типа `http://host.com/controller/action` в абсолютной форме будет таким - `http://host.com/controller/action/public/css/main.css`. И это вам точно не подойдет.